# Как убрать отступ справа у картинки (Bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Недавно начал ковырять Bootstrap. Когда верстал одну секцию заметил, что у картинок (img) появляется непонятный отступ справа. А именно 5px. Как не менял стили ничего не получилось. Надеюсь на помощь и объяснение)

```css
work {
  margin: 70px auto;
}

.work__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 320px;
  max-height: 180px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.center {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="work">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="center">
      <div class="col-xl-2">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MnDJ8xg.png" alt="work_1" class="work__img">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CCjyGSL.png" alt="work_1" class="work__img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-2 ">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JdlSYpO.png" alt="work_1" class="work__img">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MnDJ8xg.png" alt="work_1" class="work__img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-2">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CCjyGSL.png" alt="work_1" class="work__img">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JdlSYpO.png" alt="work_1" class="work__img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-2">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MnDJ8xg.png" alt="work_1" class="work__img">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CCjyGSL.png" alt="work_1" class="work__img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-2">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CCjyGSL.png" alt="work_1" class="work__img">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JdlSYpO.png" alt="work_1" class="work__img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-2">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MnDJ8xg.png" alt="work_1" class="work__img">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CCjyGSL.png" alt="work_1" class="work__img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такая проблема возникает из-за `display: inline-block`, который изображениям задаётся по умолчанию. У `inline`, `inline-block` и всего с `inline-*` есть интересная особенность: появляются отступы (опять же по умолчанию) для защиты контента от наложения друг на друга, которые не убираются через `margin` или `padding`.

Для того, чтобы от них избавиться, нужно задать блоку `display` без `inline`. Также flexbox у родительского элемента перестраивает эту логику (flexbox также понадобится, чтобы вернуть логику, как в Вашем примере). Т.е вот так будет всё работать как надо:

```css
work {
  margin: 70px auto;
}

.work__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 320px;
  max-height: 180px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.center {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.images {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="work">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="center">
      <div class="col-xl-2 images">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MnDJ8xg.png" alt="work_1" class="work__img">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CCjyGSL.png" alt="work_1" class="work__img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```